# Understanding type inference with conditional types

Tags: typescript, type-inference, conditional-types

I have trouble understanding why TypeScript infers `program.options` here as `ProgramAOptions | ProgramBOptions`. Thus it cannot compile code since `optA` does not exist in `ProgramBOptions`. Can you explain or point me to documentation which explains this behaviour?

```
type ProgramName = 'a' | 'b';

type ProgramAOptions = {
    optA: number;
};

type ProgramBOptions = {
    optB: number;
};

type Program<T extends ProgramName> = {
    name: T;
    options: T extends 'a' ? ProgramAOptions : ProgramBOptions;
};name

function test(p: Program<ProgramName>) : void
{
    if (p.name === 'a')
    {
        p.options.optA = 10; /* this line would not compile with error:

        error TS2339: Property 'optA' does not exist on type 'ProgramAOptions | ProgramBOptions'.
        Property 'optA' does not exist on type 'ProgramBOptions'.*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I'd solve your problem, by explicitly declaring interfaces for every couple of names and options:

```
type ProgramName = 'a' | 'b';

interface ProgramAOptions {
    optA: number;
};

interface ProgramBOptions {
    optB: number;
};

type ProgramOptions = ProgramAOptions | ProgramBOptions;

interface Program {
    name: ProgramName;
    options: ProgramOptions;
}

interface ProgramA extends Program {
    name: 'a';
    options: ProgramAOptions;
}

interface ProgramB extends Program {
    name: 'b';
    options: ProgramBOptions;
}

type Programs = ProgramA | ProgramB;

function test(p: Programs): void {
    if (p.name === 'a') {
        p.name // is of type "a"
        p.options.optA = 10; // Works
    }
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=35&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewOZwIYFsByHoF4oDkqBUAPoQEYEDcAsAFAMCWAdsBHAGaoDG08yNOgCCAeTDAmCFgGcoAbwZRlUBBOEAuKCwCu6Chzr0AvkeZsO3PrEQoMAIXGTpcxfRWqJ9rbv2GGpgwMoJA2ghhOUrJQ%20AJ2IpEuZGHxjhJRMmb0rOxcvPy2QgpKKiw4WnFC2OgQRh5qzrIVhRHpLkbGQdkWedaVGMJQEAAe7CwAJnL96MXupeWExHUqDRnN4Qltsh1dOZb5KUL2Q6MQE1MtM24eZTVaBFTLyqsu66mJ2wFdIQUbcrGXQbkab2LKcHQsHiNKDsGTAAAUYDeQhkAEotAA3BBMcazDxMThQREAOlueFw%20CIBFReI8KjApJwUAA9MyoEw5AhCT8oAAiVC8kp0qAMl6yYkNQb4ACMAAZqCy2QB1BBwADWMiFUE6JiAA)

Comment: This works great indeed, +1, nevertheless I would love to understand why 'conditional types' way does not.

Comment: Because [type narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) works on single variables and on union types. In your case you have a single generic type in which you provided yourself the `T` type so you give no room to type narrowing